How do I set a universal deadline to gRPC clients created by the gRPC client factory?
Following along the gRPC client factory integration in .NET I can register a gRPC client like this:
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>(o =>
{
    o.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
});

Now I would like to set a universal deadline for all calls that are made with this client. Maybe something like this:
int deadline = ReadFromConfig();

builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>(o =>
{
    o.Address = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
    o.CallOptionsActions.Add(o => () =>
        o.CallOptions.Deadline = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(deadline))
});

However, the deadline in the call options is read-only here. It seems like I cannot set it here. Am I doing it wrong, or is it only possible to set a deadline when sending out the request?

Why do you want this? A deadline isn't a timeout. What you ask is a default, not global, deadline and the docs clearly say it doesn't exist. A default deadline for all calls, even server-streaming calls, makes little sense. Do you really want to stop waiting for server events 5 seconds after you subscribe to them? Or cancel all streaming responses within 5 seconds?

The gRPC protocol itself has no timeouts. The gRPC documentation explains why. The deadline applies to all the intermediate calls by all the services involved in a gRPC call. If someone calls A which calls your service, the original caller's timeline also applies to your service. Instead of having clients and multiple services trying to calculate how much time each has left, gRPC specifies a specific deadline instant that applies as-is for all services

Hey, thanks for your reply. I should maybe clarify that I don't have streams for this service, only unary RPCs. I want universal deadlines for different reasons, f.e. I want to set universal client-side deadlines that are shorter than the gateway timeouts between the client and the  server, to get a response from the server before that. Looking at this snippet again it is obviously wrong, I should register a function to calculate the current UTC time + timeout to generate a deadline.

For now I calculate and set the deadline for each call, I guess that is supposed how it is done. Another option I considered is an interceptor, that adds the deadline to the context. It would be nice to set some universal timeout to the client for different reasons, e.g. the gateway timeout that I mentioned. Or is that bad practice?

Completely untested, but how about an Interceptor ?
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://whatever");
var invoker = channel.Intercept(new DeadlineInterceptor(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
// TODO: create your client from "invoker", not "channel"


class DeadlineInterceptor(TimeSpan deadline) : Interceptor
{
    private void ApplyDeadline<TRequest, TResponse>(ref ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context)
        where TRequest : class
        where TResponse : class
    {
        if (context.Options.Deadline is null)
        {
            context = new(context.Method, context.Host, context.Options.WithDeadline(DateTime.UtcNow.Add(deadline)));
        }
    }

    public override AsyncClientStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse> AsyncClientStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncClientStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ApplyDeadline(ref context);
        return base.AsyncClientStreamingCall(context, continuation);
    }

    public override AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse> AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncDuplexStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ApplyDeadline(ref context);
        return base.AsyncDuplexStreamingCall(context, continuation);
    }

    public override AsyncServerStreamingCall<TResponse> AsyncServerStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncServerStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ApplyDeadline(ref context);
        return base.AsyncServerStreamingCall(request, context, continuation);
    }

    public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ApplyDeadline(ref context);
        return base.AsyncUnaryCall(request, context, continuation);
    }

    public override TResponse BlockingUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        ApplyDeadline(ref context);
        return base.BlockingUnaryCall(request, context, continuation);
    }

    // note no need to intercept server methods
}


Yup, thanks a lot, an interceptor is what also was my next thought. For now I decided to pass the config value trough the app and calculate the deadline before I make the call and add it directly, but arguably an interceptor could be nicer. I wasn't sure if I can modify the deadline of the context here or if it would still be read-only here, that is why I went straight to the other approach. Would you have any preferences between an interceptor and directly adding the deadline to the call?

@dan-kli it will be easier to feel confident that an interceptor is being applied consistently and universally; there will be a tiny abstraction overhead, but frankly that won't be relevant in any IPC or RPC scenario, so: meh

Edit: I saw that you are creating a new context, so my read-only argument is invalid. Nice interceptor! Thanks!
